# RX IObservable as a Pipeline

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, system.reactive, pipeline

Currently, I'm using the RX Framework to implement a workflow-like message handling pipeline. Essentially I have a message producer (deserializes network messages and calls OnNext() on a Subject) and I have several consumers.

NOTE: If and transform are extension methods I have coded that simply return an IObservable.

A consumer does something like the following:

```
 var commerceRequest = messages.Transform(x => GetSomethingFromDatabase(x)
                              .Where(y => y.Value > 5)
                              .Select(y => y.ComplexObject)
                              .If(z => z.IsPaid, respond(z))
                              .Do(z => SendError(z));
```

`commerceRequest` is then consumed by another similar pipeline and this continues up until the top where it ends with someone calling `Subscribe()` on the final pipeline. The issue I'm having is that the messages from the base don't propagate up unless subscribe is called on messages directly somewhere.

How can I push the messages up to the top of the stack? I know this is an unorthodox approach but I feel it makes the code very simple to understand what is occurring to a message. Can anyone suggest another way of doing the same if you feel this is a totally terrible idea?

Comment: Yeah... in my view, anything in this general style of OO is going to look somewhat pipeline-ish. And that's a good thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should they go through the pipeline if there are no subscribers?  If one of your intermediate steps is useful for their side-effects (You want them to run even if there are no other subscribers), you should rewrite the side-effect operation to be a subscriber.

You could also make the step with a side-effect as a pass-through operation (or tee, if you will) if you wanted to continue the chain.